# Recent Photos mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this:

```
userID | photo_name | upload_date(unixtimestamp) | title
```

I want to output to look like this

```
userID1 photo1.jpg photo2.jpg photo3.jpg

userID2 photo1.jpg photo2.jpg

userID3 photo1.jpg photo2.jpg photo3.jpg
```

Showing the recent photos uploaded limited 3 photos per userID
Thank you :)

Comment: the question is a little confusing... maybe a little more explanation would help.

Comment: To show the recent 3 photos uploaded by each member

Comment: ah... that makes more sense so do you just want the mysql query?

Comment: @max and is there a way to tell how many users there are?

Answer (score 0):

You can get halfway there with `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT userID, GROUP_CONCAT(photo_name SEPARATOR ' ') FROM table GROUP BY userID;
```

Unfortunately, there is no support for limiting the number of things that are concatenated. You'll just need to process the result.

Comment: how does this give the most recent items ?